# how to make a class like int or bool in c++?

Tags: c++, class

When we make a class we use of c++ standard objects like a bool int or double. but I want to know how to make a class which does not use of c++ object to make something like bool or int.
 In other words how does c++ compiler makers make int or bool?

Comment: Those aren't classes, they're built-in types. They aren't written as a library type.

Comment: While those are built-in basic types and not classes, you can make a class that *behaves* as one of the built-in basic types.

Comment: Of course you inherently have to use some built-in type to make that class.

Comment: Are you looking for the data models used for built-in types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using classes, there is no functionality given in c++ to create new types that would act like numbers.

You can create aliases to existing types with `using Int32 = int32_t;`

Existing types, like `int` or `bool` are defined by the compiler as intrinsics.

Comment: @JBentley: I'd be surprised. `int512_t x; x += 3;`. What are you going to preprocess that to? What if this is actually part of a templated function?